# How to compute with sparse tensors in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I want to implement this formula from the DNC implementation in TensorFlow in a batch fashion.

[image: eqn1]
[image: eqn2]
[image: eqn3]

With batch dense tensors it's pretty straight forward.

```
# w [B, N], p [B, N], L [B, N, N], B=batch_size
dot_prod = tf.batch_matmul(tf.expand_dims(w, axis=2), tf.expand_dims(p, axis=1))
one_prod = 1 - tf.expand_dims(w, 1) - tf.expand_dims(w, 2) 
L =  one_prod * pre_L + dot_prod
```

Is there a way to implement this with sparse tensors? ***w***, ***p*** and ***L*** are sparse but TensorFlow lacks on sparse batch matmul and sparse indexing.

Comment: What about the options `a_is_sparse` and `b_is_sparse` in `tf.matmul`? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions#matmul

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not support batches.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting into a dense tensor:

`tf.sparse_to_dense(
    sparse_indices,
    output_shape,
    sparse_values,
    default_value=0,
    validate_indices=True,
    name=None
)`

Usage example:
`mat = tf.sparse_to_dense(inds, [n, class_size], vals)`

See docs here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense